# How to implement jQuery.panzoom with node & browserify

Tags: node.js, browserify, jquery.panzoom

On the [plugin's github page](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom) there is the following explanation to implement the plugin via AMD loader:

```js
define([ "jquery", "plugins/jquery.panzoom" ], function( $ ) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".panzoom-elements").panzoom();
  });
});
```

But how do I implement this plugin via nodejs & browserify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin uses UMD (Universal Module Definition) pattern, meaning you could use it also with CommonJS/Browserify module system as usual like any other lib/package.

(See: [these lines of source code](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom/blob/734dadfe6614b1e49c68081ca06e73c76597fdf3/dist/jquery.panzoom.js#L16-L18)).

**Installation**:

```
npm install jquery.panzoom --save
```

**Usage**:

*main.js*

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('jquery.panzoom');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panzoom-elements").panzoom();
});
```

**Browserify**:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Comment: Well, I copy pasted this code and it worked! I don't fully get it though. 
What I first did was: "var panzoom = require('jquery.panzoom');". That gave the error: "panzoom is not a function". Apparantly that DOES work because of the $ require before the panzoom require. I can do jQuery stuff on my files because I included jQuery via HTML script, so I don't get why I HAVE to require it in JS in order for this to work. The $ object is global..

Comment: As a browserify best practice always remember to Include all dependencies in every module you need it in. Here we need `jQuery` and `Panzoom` so included both.

Comment: I just don't get why it doesn't recognise my jQuery included in the HTML, I can do jQuery stuff in all my files. Now jQuery is also included in my app.js so it's unnecessary bandwidth :)

Comment: What is `Browserify` ?